# Go Timer Deadlock on Stop

Tags: go

I am trying to reuse timers by stopping and resetting them. I am following the pattern provided by the documentation. Here is a simple example which can be run in go playground that demonstrates the issue I am experiencing.

Is there a correct way to stop and reset a timer that doesn't involve deadlock or race conditions? I am aware that using a select with default involves a race condition on channel message delivery timing and cannot be depended on.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    timer := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    go func(_wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        <- timer.C
        fmt.Println("Timer done")
        _wg.Done()
    }(wg)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Checking timer")
    if !timer.Stop() {
        <- timer.C
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Comment: There's another unrelated bug here within your go-routine, you should be doing `_wg.Done()` to use the passed in WaitGroup. You are referencing the other scoped wg (which is the same entity) - but if you are going to the trouble of passing in the value, you should reference the parameter value.

Comment: Good catch, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [timer.Stop](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) docs, there is a caveat for draining the channel:

> assuming the program has **not** received from t.C already ...
>
> This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's
>   channel.

Since the channel has already been drained - and will never fire again, the second `<-timer.C` will block forever.

Comment: The documentation does not say to do this. It says to drain the channel after stop returns false, then reset. It doesn’t seem to make much sense to me to reset before draining.

Comment: If I’m going to reset it after I know I’ve received its message, shouldn’t I do that in the async go routine handling the original message?

Comment: From: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop it reads "This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's channel."

Comment: Re coordination  - you know the timer has fired after wg.Wait() completes.

Comment: Correct, it is not done concurrent to other receives; that is the purpose of the wait group. This example is an attempt to create a minimum example of real code that I am writing and experiencing unexpected deadlocks with.

Comment: I suppose the fact that I know that the timer has fired (a precondition for draining the channel via the wait group) means this contrived example would always deadlock, as I would need to reset the timer in the async routine which first drained it.

Comment: I do agree the docs are confusing. There's a very narrow situation where one would need to do that sort of cleanup.

Comment: My real life situation is that I create thousands of go routines which wait for signals on certain channels (message, timeout, periodic check, reset, etc.), and I observed a deadlock on draining this timer channel in one of these routines which blocked all upstream messages from being sent. This drain happened in a select block for a channel unrelated to the timer message, so I thought it quite strange that I could both be not the one that stopped it but also not the one that drained it. At least now I can have a clearer mental model of the processing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The question asks, in the first place, why the timer hangs. That's a good question, because even in the absence of bugs in the user program, there is... at least some weird ambiguity in how this thing, called time.Timer, works in Go. The spec says, specifically this:

> Stop prevents the Timer from firing. It returns true if the call stops
> the timer, false if the timer has already expired or been stopped.
> Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a read from the channel
> succeeding incorrectly.
>
> To ensure the channel is empty after a call to Stop, check the return
> value and drain the channel. For example, assuming the program has not
> received from t.C already:
>
> ```
> if !t.Stop() {
>   <-t.C
> }
> ```
>
> This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's
> channel or other calls to the Timer's Stop method.

There are very short and precise words, but it may be not that easy to understand them (at least for me). I tried to use the Timer repeatedly in a piece of code, and reset it each time before the next use. Each time I do so, I may want to Stop() it - just for sure. The spec above implies how you should do that, and provides an example - and it may not work! It depends, it depends *where* you try to apply the Stop idiom. In case you do it after you already in a select-case on this very timer, then it will hang the program.

Specifically, I do not have any concurrent receivers, only a single goroutine. So let's make a simple test program, and try to experiment with it (https://play.golang.org/p/d7BlNReE9Jz):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    d2s := time.Second * 1
    
    i++; fmt.Println(i)
    
    t := time.NewTimer(d2s)
    <-t.C
    i++; fmt.Println(i)

    t.Reset(d2s)
    <-t.C
    i++; fmt.Println(i)

//  if !t.Stop() { <-t.C }
//  if !t.Stop() { select { case <-t.C: default: } }
    t.Reset(d2s)
    <-t.C
    i++; fmt.Println(i)

}
```

This code WORKS. It prints 1,2,3,4, delayed by 1 sec, and that's what it is expected to print. So far so good.

Now, try to un-comment the first commented line. Now the thing: **according to spec, it is 100% right (is it?), and must work**, but it does not, and hangs. Why? Because, **according to spec, it must hang**! I already read the channel, and the timer is stopped, so the `if` fires, and the channel drain op hangs.

Is this a bug? No. Is the spec wrong? No, it's correct. But, it's contrary to what a typical timer user would want. (Maybe a subject for proposal to Go?). All we need, is something like:

```
t.SafeStopDrain()
```

Which would do this right, and never hang. But, sadly, it is non-existent.

Here's the life-hack, the workaround, to make this work, is the second commented line. Un-comment it, and that will both **work**, and do what you wanted - make sure the timer is stopped, channel drained, and the whole thing is fresh anew for re-use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I understand your confusion in the code you wrote, it wasn't clear to me at first, either. The reason it hangs is due to the fact that you have already read from the timer channel after it had expired, so no more messages will come through (as you know). What's missing from your perspective is that you, as the "manager" of this single thread, necessarily must know that the timer has been stopped (by virtue of you having read from the timer channel already).